# How to split up an email body that contains replies (i.e. an email thread)?

Tags: python, email, imap

I am reading an email body using the python `imap` and `email` libraries:

```py
import imaplib
from email import message_from_bytes

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
imap.login(email_address, pw)
_, output = imap.fetch("100", "(RFC822)")
raw_output = output[0]
msg = message_from_bytes(raw_output[1])
body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
```

However, the body has the replies of many other emails in a chain:

```
second reply
________________________________
From: bob <bob@gmail.com>
Sent: 10 December 2022 11:35
To: susan <susan@outlook.com>
Subject: Re: creating a test thread

first reply

On 10 Dec 2022, at 11:34, blah dev <susan@outlook.com<mailto:susan@outlook.com>> wrote:

first message
```

Is there an easy way/library to strip/split the replies in the chain (especially given that the reply formatting seems to vary between email providers)?
i.e. something like a list `["second reply", "first reply", "first message" ]`

Comment: There may be libraries that can do this heuristically, but in general, no.  Even major email clients get it wrong sometime and can't tell when a reply begins but there's no standard for it and every client does their own thing.

Comment: Ah, bummer. Thanks for the heads up. I will keep this thread open to see if anyone has any suggestions for libraries